# Converting from java to MIPS assembly with arrays

Tags: java, assembly, mips, mips32

```
> int i  = n-1;
while(i > 0){
int j  = 0;
while(j < i){
//Do stuff
if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) { // If they are out of order, swap them
          int tmp = arr[j];
          arr[j] = arr[j+1];
          arr[j+1] = tmp;
i++;
}

i--;
}
```

---

Converting this java code to MIPS assembly. Here is the MIPS I have so far,

## $s0= start of the array   $s5 is the end.

```
Addi $s1, $s5, -1;

While:
Slt $t0, 0, $s1
Beq $t0, $zero, done;

Addi $s2, 1, -1; 
While:

Slt $t1, $s2, $s1;
Beq $t1, $zero, done;

Sll $ts, $t1, 2;
```

The last part is the start of the arr[j], and I'm confused on how to initialize the if statement. And the increments, could someone show me the rest?

Comment: Unless this is homework, you can use [`javat`](http://sep.stanford.edu/oldsep/matt/jest/jdocs/tools/javat.html) which translates compiled Java bytecode into MIPS instructions.

Comment: I will be tested on it.. so I need an explanation of the next steps.

Comment: @MickMnemonic there is not javat.exe in jdk/bin folder, also I searched javat keyword on google and nobody talked about, how can we achive this tool ?

Comment: @AhmetCanAkgül, look at the link in my comment above.

Comment: Okay, seems like there is no download link. [Here](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/java/v1_1_6/translation.html) is one more site that could help.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic i have been searching for javat for hours now haha i went through every jdk oracle had and its not in any. Do you have any idea how to get it?